# Adding custom godaddy domain to railway web app

Tags: python, django, deployment, dns

I deployed my web app on [Railway](https://railway.app/).

They gave the following settings:
[image]

I went to GoDaddy where I bought a custom domain - and it was impossible to enter @ as Name. I called support - their representative entered the following settings himself.
[image]
But it still doesn't work, 72 hours have passed.

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I am experiencing same problem too, did you get it to work? please it's urgent

Comment: I'am facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

To set up both your apex/root domain and `www` subdomain with Railway, follow these  steps.

**On Railway**

1. Go to the 'Settings' tab of your project, and scroll down to the 'Domains' section.
2. Add your root domain and `www` subdomain as follows:
   [image: Railway project settings screenshot]

**On Domain Registrar**

Go to your domain manager, and add the following DNS records:

| Type | Hostname | Address/Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) | railway-provided-domain |
| A | example.com | Remote Address of railway-provided-domain |

- `railway-provided-domain` is `web-production-9d39.up.railway.app` in your case.
- The value for `A` record can be found by going to `railway-provided-domain`, opening the Network tab, and obtaining the Remote Address.

Wait for some time after completing these steps, and your custom domain should be up and running with Railway.

Comment: The Remote Address won't work after some time as the "example.com" ip you set is not fixed for Railway services

Answer (score 2):

I manage to do it!

In the railway -> settings -> domains -> + custom domain

- put your domain with **[www.your-domain.com](http://www.your-domain.com)**    (it will give you the
  same settings as above but instead of **@** will be **www**)
- put another without the www,  **your-domain.com** (it will give you the
  same settings as above but instead of using the railway domain use the IP, like @James said)

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I get it to work by adding in railway the domain wwww.your-domain.com instead of your-domain.com.

Then on go daddy added the CNAME with the name www and the value from railway,

then scroll below dns records, down to forwarding, and at domain, click add forwarding and add the destionation: https:// and [www.your-domain.com](http://www.your-domain.com), and forward type permanent (301).

I had to wait 10 minutes until both urls worked (your-domain.com and [www.your-domain.com](http://www.your-domain.com)).

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. The best way to solve it is actually by changing the NS (Name Servers).

Here's how I solved it:

Some domain registrars don't fully support CNAME records root domain. Consequently when you add an @ record for a CNAME, the domain registrar will create an invalid A record.
In your case, your domain provider doesn't support CNAME record with the name '@' (root aka apex).
To set a root CNAME record, you can use cloudflare's Name Servers. They does what's called 'CNAME flattening' to use a CNAME record at your root/apex domain ( example.com ).

here's a 5 step sollution:

1. first open a cloudflare account
2. click on Add a Site and add your domain
3. After adding your site, cloudflare will provide you two nameservers
4. Go to your Domain provider and change the name servers to the ones given by cloudflare.

This may take a little while but once it's done, you'll no longer need to go to your domain provider to change your DNS records.

5. Once the name servers are updated, go to cloudflare dashboard and select DNS from the left side panel. Here, you can set the CNAME record provided by Railway.

That's it!

I found the solution on this [documentation](https://docs.railway.app/deploy/exposing-your-app#custom-domains) by railway.

Comment: It's Not working and some other problems are coming like a,aaaa,cname already exist and not added any . Can you help ??

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work temporarily by doing the following things:

1. Add a CNAME entry with the name `www` and value as `<value provided by railway>`
2. open `www.<hostname>.com`, open the network tab and get the IP of the website.
3. Add the A entry with the name as `@` and the value to be set as `<IP from the second step>`

I know this is a workaround and not a full proof solution. I will update as I figure it out myself.

PS: GoDaddy's customer support was very stubborn and didn't provide much help.

Comment: I don't think it is a solution as Railway uses CDN and the IP is very specific to my location.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect, following this up will result in an eventual failure due to them changing their DNS records and where they point to.